# Provision failed is retured but provision happened not connected to bluetooth in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below code device in provision mode .Now My agenda is change provision to data and connecting via and wifi and bluetooth.

But In the below code after calling provision method giving me provision failed as response but it is connected to wifi.

But want to connect both wifi and bluetooth.

Can any one help me where I did the mistake.

java1:

```
 bleName = uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.BLE_NAME); // BLE_NAME | for testing
                    pop = uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.POP_NAME);
                    Log.d("jyothi", "" + bleName);
                    String prefix = "PESPROV_" + bleName;
                    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                            (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
                    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        context.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    }
                    BluetoothLeScanner scanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                    scanDevice(context, "PESPROV_", bleName);
                    scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                            String deviceName = result.getScanRecord().getDeviceName();
                            if (result.getDevice() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(deviceName)) {
                                // Found BLE device
                                Log.d(TAG, "========== Device Found : " + deviceName);
                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    // TODO: Consider calling
                                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                    return;
                                }
                                scanner.startScan(scanCallback);
                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(prefix)) {
                                    pesManager.onPeripheralFound(result.getDevice(), result);
                                } else if (deviceName.startsWith(prefix)) {
                                    pesManager.onPeripheralFound(result.getDevice(), result);
                                    if (result.getScanRecord().getServiceUuids() != null && !result.getScanRecord().getServiceUuids().isEmpty()) {
                                        serviceUuid = result.getScanRecord().getServiceUuids().get(0).toString();
                                    }
                                    pesManager.connectBleDevices(result.getDevice(), serviceUuid);
                                    pesManager.getEspDevice().setProofOfPossession(pop);
                                    pesBleDevice.bleDevice = pesManager.getBleDevice(result.getDevice().getAddress());
                                    pesBleDevice.connectToBleGattServer(pesBleDevice.bleDevice, context);
                                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                                        pesBleDevice.discoverServiced();
                                    }, 1000);
                                    try {
                                        wifiAccesspointName = Constant.SSID;
                                        wifiAccesspointPassword =Constant.PASS_PHASE;
                                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                                        pesManager.provision(wifiAccesspointName, wifiAccesspointPassword);
                                       }, 20000);

                                        String nonceStr = ""; //uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.NONCE); // // stable
                                        Log.d("jyothi","nonceStr"+nonceStr);

                                        String provUrl = "";//uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.PROVISIONING_URL); // //provision
                                        pesManager.sendPesNonce(provUrl, nonceStr);
                                        Log.d("jyothi","nonceStr"+nonceStr);
                                        Timber.tag("PES").i("PesNative-Inside performPesConnectivity method | Completed Executing Network Select Api Call");


                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
                            super.onBatchScanResults(results);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
                        }
                    };
                    scanner.startScan(scanCallback);

                }
                String nonceStr = ""; //uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.NONCE); // // stable
                Log.d("jyothi","nonceStr"+nonceStr);

                String provUrl = "";//uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.PROVISIONING_URL); // //provision
                pesManager.sendPesNonce(provUrl, nonceStr);
                Log.d("jyothi","nonceStr"+nonceStr);
                Timber.tag("PES").i("PesNative-Inside performPesConnectivity method | Completed Executing Network Select Api Call");
```

java2:

```
public void provision(String ssidValue,String passphraseValue) {
      
        Log.d(TAG, "Wifi provisioning started...");
        Timber.tag("PES").i("PesNative-Inside provision method | Wi-fi provisioning started...");
        try{
            provisionManager.getEspDevice().provision(ssidValue, passphraseValue,this);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```